# Question about real step random variables

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I am reading J. Neveu's book "Mathematical Foundations of the Calculus of Probability" and am stuck on his definition of a real step random variable (step r.r.v). His definition is as follows: A real step random variable on ($\Omega$,$\mathbb{A}$) is a mapping into the real line $\mathbb{R}$ of the form $$X(\omega)=x_i$$ if $ \omega \in A_i$ and $\{A_i\}_i$ are a finite partition of ($\Omega$,$\mathbb{A}$) and the real numbers $x_i$ are pairwise distinct. So far so good.

However, in the next part he has the following proposition: In order that a mapping $X$ into $\mathbb{R}$ be a step r.r.v, it is necessary and sufficient that $X^{-1}(\mathbb{B})$ be a finite $\sigma$-subalgebra of $\mathbb{A}$, where $\mathbb{B}$ is the Borel $\sigma-$algebra. It is necessary since $X^{-1}(\mathbb{B})$ is identical with the $\sigma$-algbera generated by the $\{A_i\}$. I agree that the inverse mapping of Borel sets is equal to the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\{A_i\}$. What I don't understand is how this relates to $X$ being a step r.r.v? It looks like I'm missing something quite essential here.

Answer (score 1):

The statement "$X^{-1}(\mathbb{B})$ is a $\sigma$-subalgebra of $\mathbb{A}$" says that $X$ is measurable with respect to $\mathbb{A}$, which is part of the definition of a random variable.  The "finite" part in the statement implies that $X$ takes on only finitely many values, and therefore is a step random variable.

Comment: Hi, Neveu defines here a step r.r.v. without requiring it be measurable.

Comment: @daniel I interpreted the statement "$\{A_i\}_i$ are a finite partition of $(\Omega,\mathbb{A})$" to mean that $A_i \in \mathbb{A}$ for all $i$ and $\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i = \Omega$.  Otherwise, what would it mean to be a partition of $(\Omega, \mathbb{A})$ rather than just a partition of $\Omega$?

Comment: Thanks for answering. I also thought about the same interpretation. I agree that otherwise it doesn't make sense. Just wanted to see what others think. Thanks again!